# DNS Resolving Issue For Mavericks

Tags: macos, networking, dns, routing

I am observing a weird issue on my Mac running Mavericks (OS 10.9.5). I am able to browse any website without any connectivity issues. However, when I check my nslookup results, I am observing weird outputs.

For example, if I try to resolve www.rubygems.org, I observe the following output on the terminal:

```
> rubygems.org
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.153

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   rubygems.org
Address: 0.1.202.53
```

Another example - I am not having any issues in accessing the Facebook website. However, when I try to obtain the traceroute output, again I see the following:

```
traceroute to www.facebook.com (0.1.202.146), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
traceroute: sendto: No route to host
 1 traceroute: wrote www.facebook.com 52 chars, ret=-1
 *traceroute: sendto: No route to host
traceroute: wrote www.facebook.com 52 chars, ret=-1
```

The reason why I am highlighting these issues is due to the similar problems I am facing while trying to provision Vagrant virtual development environment on my laptop.

If I try provisioning the Vagrant plugin for AWS (Amazon Web Services) using the terminal, I observe the following issue in the output:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
Installing the 'vagrant-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing fog-sakuracloud (0.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/gems/fog-sakuracloud-0.1.1.gem)
```

As you can see above, I am unable to reach the site https://rubygems.org/gems/fog-sakuracloud-0.1.1.gem. However, when I try accessing the site through my browser, I am not having any issues in downloading the gem file.

I am facing similar issues in executing other commands on the terminal which involves downloading any files or packages from the internet.

Can someone please advise how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [your dig output](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/98a3f11078edb243f1d8), you are receiving these DNS responses from 192.168.1.1 (presumably your home router/gateway).

```
;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 20 20:31:00 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

I'm pretty suspicious of SOHO routers and their ability to do recursive DNS in general.  I would suggest updating your DNS server to something more resilient.  There are many to choose from, but for simplicity, to test and rule out your router, just use [Google's Open Resolvers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

To test against them before even changing any configuration items, run this:
`dig rubygems.org @8.8.8.8`.  Post the output here.  When I do it, I get this:

```
16:06:28-eddie@linux:~$ dig rubygems.org @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> rubygems.org @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30950
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;rubygems.org.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
rubygems.org.           237     IN      A       54.186.104.15

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 20 16:06:44 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

Comment: Hi @Eddie, thanks for following up here. Here is the output you requested - [Dig @8](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/7e3e6425a38ba5d41738)

I guess the issue is with the SOHO router.

Comment: Hi @Eddie, some new findings. Looks like its not an issue with the SOHO router DNS settings. I tried the same commands you provided earlier with my friend's laptop as we are using the same WiFi network connected via the SOHO router and everything seems to be working fine on his laptop. Here's the dig [output](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/5ba38eccf8a1b2c42ab7)

I noticed I am running a VPN software on my laptop. Although it is turned off, could it have caused some issues with my DNS table?

Comment: I don't think it is your SOHO router afterall, given the same **dig** results going against Google's DNS server's vs your SOHO router.  It definitely seems like something is messing with your DNS resolving, though, because you should have gotten the same thing I got when I did the dig "against" Google's DNS Servers.  Are you currently connected to a VPN somewhere?  If so, can you try the same tests disconnected from the VPN?

Comment: Can you resolve other sites?  Try mensa.org, chainlove.com, woot.com.  Do it on your computer and on the new laptop, see if you get the same results both times.

Comment: Hi @Eddie, I think there is some confusion here. I can clearly see the difference in the dig results against Google's DNS. Let me clarify the name of the different outputs so that we are on the same page.  1. [Dig Output](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/98a3f11078edb243f1d8) is the first output without the VPN 2. [Dig New Laptop](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/5ba38eccf8a1b2c42ab7) is the output from my friend's laptop 3. [Dig Without VPN](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/a7474b32addcb9aec71e) is the second output without the VPN which **I have just taken now**

Comment: Hi @Eddie, here you go. I have taken the output for the 3 new sites on both the [Problematic](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/2b287d421bf801fbacb2) laptop and the [Working](https://gist.github.com/fardeenrahaman/7863e5d25cd4127005df) laptop. As you can see, it's clearly an issue with my laptop's DNS table. And these are taken without the VPN being switched on. Is it possible that the VPN DNS table has conflicted with my normal DNS table?

Comment: I think we've definitely determined the problem is on your MAC Laptop somewhere.  Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with the MAC OS,  I'm not going to be much help in suggesting troubleshooting steps.  You should try to contact someone that is, maybe visit an apple store to see what they have.  You could see if there is a way to reboot into an iteration of the OS with no additional services installed, to see if it is one of those that is causing issues.   Sorry I can't be much more help.

Comment: No worries @Eddie Thanks for all the help. I will take it from here and post the resolution once I find it.

Comment: Hi @Eddie, I managed to solve the problem. All that it required was a reboot of the laptop in order to flush the DNS cache. Right after things are good. I am able to see similar outputs for the dig command as seen on the working laptop. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the DNS cache which was populated with the DNS table of the VPN software I was running on my Macbook.

I rebooted my Macbook and the issue was resolved immediately as the DNS cache was reset.

I looked up online later and found that a hard reset such as rebooting the laptop was not necessary, although it is the standard practice followed by most when troubleshooting such issues in the presence of a VPN software.

One can also do a soft reset by flushing the DNS. There is a good tutorial as how one can do this on Windows, Mac or Linux on [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Flush-DNS)